# Odoo 11 sales order confirm button override

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding, odoo, odoo-11

I tried overriding the sales order confirm button with the below code:

```
class sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    @api.multi
    def action_confirm(self):
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        rec = super(sale_order, self).action_confirm()
        _logger.debug("this_action_took_place_sales")
        _logger.error('this_action_took_place_sales %s', "sales")
        return rec
```

I restarted the server and upgraded the code. Even then I do not see the message in the logs.

I read this answer: 
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/sale-override-action-button-confirm-116695 
and wrote the below code:

```
@api.multi
def action_button_confirm(self):
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    rec = super(sale_order, self).action_button_confirm()
    _logger.debug("this_action_took_place_sales")
    _logger.error('this_action_took_place_sales %s', "sales")
    return rec
```

No logs even then.
I checked the parent sales order file. (sale.py). The method over there is named action_confirm(self)

What is the correct way to override the sales confirm action button in odoo 11?

Comment: Check whether your file gets loaded during startup at all: is it in `__init__.py` ? if there's an intentional syntax error, does it fail on startup?

Answer (score 0):

That method in Odoo v9 was renamed to `action_confirm`, the link referenced from the Odoo forum refers to Odoo v8 where the method was `action_button_confirm`. Just rename it to the new method name and you will be fine from v9 to v11